# Trigger Add Partition

Tags: oracle, plsql

ERROR TO EXECUTE, ERROR DATE, WHICH FORMAT TO USE?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prc_partitionFN (data IN DATE, name IN VARCHAR2)
AS
 a VARCHAR2(400);
 d DATE;
BEGIN

    SELECT TO_DATE(data , 'YYYY/MM')INTO d
    FROM dual;

    a := 'ALTER TABLE fornitore_negozio ADD PARTITION name VALUES LESS THAN (d)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE a;

    dbms_output.put_line('Partizione creata correttamente');
    END prc_partitionFN;
```

Comment: `data` it's not a column you can select from dual. What kind of date you want to retrieve?

Comment: variable `data` is a `DATE` - **NEVER** call `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE`.

Comment: What is the data type of your partition key? Hopefully it is a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) data type then you can use [Interval Partitioning](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/partitioning-enhancements-11gr1#interval_partitioning). An Interval Partitioned table creates new partitions automatically and you don't have to care about it.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you converting the date to again date?

I think you need the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_PARTITIONFN (
    DATA   IN     DATE,
    NAME   IN     VARCHAR2
) AS
    A   VARCHAR2(400);
BEGIN

    A := 'ALTER TABLE fornitore_negozio ADD PARTITION name VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('''
         || TO_CHAR(DATA, 'YYYY/MM')
         || ',''YYYY/MM'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE A;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Partizione creata correttamente');
END PRC_PARTITIONFN;
```

Comment: The procedure does not work, variable `D` is not declared. You ask (absolutely right) "Why are you converting the date again to date?" - but you do similar in your answer. `select ... from dual` use useless, simply write `D := ...;`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Actually I forgot to remove that `select ... from dual` . It is not needed at all

Comment: Tejash how should I put the date in execution?

Comment: See the updated answer. and you are using the dynamic query so the date will be converted to char. You need to convert it to date using `to_date` as shown in updated answer!!

Comment: Variable `name` is not used in dynamic sql string.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I think `DATA` is the variable name